# VHDL - Can't understand why this code works on my FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to create a very simple watch (I don't use the word "clock" to avoid misunderstandings) on my FPGA (it displays seconds, minutes and hours) for an assignment and a friend of mine gave me some code that actually works when I synthesize it on my FPGA, but I can't understand why. Here's the main process.

```
main: process(clk)
begin

    if((clk='1' and clk'event) and en='1') then
        if(init = '0') then
            sec <= conv_integer(seconds_in);
            min <= conv_integer(minutes_in);
            hour <= conv_integer(hours_in);
            init <= '1';
        else
            count <= count + 1;
            if(count = 1000000) then
                sec <= sec+1;
                count <= 0;
                if(sec=59) then
                    min <= min+1;
                    sec <= 0;
                    if(min=59) then
                        hour <= hour+1;
                        min <= 0;
                        if(hour=23) then
                            hour <= 0;
                            count <= 0;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;

end process main;
```

It starts by initializing the integers `sec`, `min` and `hour` to the initial value set by the user. Then, it does the actual work of incrementing the variables every second, minute or hour. The frequency of `clk` is 1 MHz.

Reading the code, it seems that `hour` (for istance) should increment just after `min` turns to 59, without waiting a full minute. But, when I synthesize it on the FPGA, it works fine, just as you would expect. Unfortunately, I can't run a simulation. Maybe this has something to do with the scheduling of the process? I'm still a beginner and maybe I'm missing something.

[EDIT]
Thanks to the comments, I noticed a small error in the code above (`count` was not correctly reset). Fixed it!

Comment: In `min <= min + 1; if (min=59)`, if `min` is 59 at the start of the process, its *next* value (after the process has ended) will be 0, but it is still 59 during the whole process, so the body of the `if` will be executed.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 . So I assume that the same applies if `min` is 58 at the start of the process: in this case, the `if` will _not_ be executed and `min` will be incremented only after the process has ended. Did I understand correctly? Anyway, does this happen even if `min` is an integer variable and not a signal?

Comment: It works like this *because* `min` is a signal. If it were a variable, it would be updated immediately within the process and the logic would have to be written differently. Whether it's an integer (its *type*) is an orthogonal concept to whether it's a signal or a variable.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. I originally thought that `min` was a variable, while it is (as you correctly pointed out) a signal.

Comment: And DOES it actually work? It looks to me as if it doesn't clear COUNT prroperly every second.

Comment: I agree that it looks like `count` fails to get reset when it should. if a 20-bit signal was used, you probably wouldn't notice because it would only run 5% slow (`2**20` is only 5% larger than `10**6`, at which point a 20 bit signal would roll over implicitly).

Comment: Yes, you're both right. `count` should be reset after the increment of `sec`. I'll edit the post.